# Fragment onActivityResult not called, instead the Activity onActivityResult is called

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, androidx, google-pay

I am trying to implement Google Pay in a project, right now the Google Pay bottom sheet opens up from a certain fragment using `AutoResolveHelper` and it requires `Activity` and not just `Context`, so naturally when the result comes it calls the `Activity`'s `onActivityResult` and not the `Fragment`'s, i have tried calling the `Fragment`'s `onActivityResult` from the `Activity`'s and nothing happens, i am also using the `Navigation Component` in `Androidx`, i have no idea if this is affecting it or what

here's the `AutoResolveHelper` code

```
AutoResolveHelper.resolveTask(
            paymentsClient.loadPaymentData(paymentDataRequest),
            requireActivity(), LOAD_PAYMENT_DATA_REQUEST_CODE)
```

these are the 2 ways i tried calling the `Fragment`'s `onActivityResult` from the `Activity`

```
var fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.paymentFragment)
    fragment?.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)


val fragments = supportFragmentManager.fragments
    if (fragments != null) {
        for (fragment in fragments) {
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you go into more detail on how you called the fragment's onActivityResult from the activitiy? imo that should work as expected

Comment: updated my question with the code

Comment: Thank you. Have you verified that you actually find the correct fragment?

Comment: first method, the fragment is null, second method it calls the onActivityResult for all active fragments i believe

Comment: Then your problem lies in finding a correct reference to the fragment. If the first method returns null for the expected fragment, the second will aswell. You should focus on figuring out why your supportFragmentManager isn't giving you the required fragment reference. How do you initially open the paymentFragment?

Comment: with an action from a previous fragment

Comment: apparently i was getting the fragment with a wrong id, now with the correct id the instance is not null, still won't work though